# ffmpeg not using wildcard properly from batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg

What I want to do is actually super simple and is working just fine if executed from within the cmd window, though it does not work when used within a batch script. The following command would normally get all .png files with the pattern anim_xxxx.png (%04d stands for 4 numbers in ffmpeg).

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i anim_%04d.png -vcodec mjpeg -q:v 0 -r 25 foo.avi
```

Now the error I get is with the wildcard for my image sequence and I have no clue what the problem is. Using another wildcard like * gives me the same error.

> [image2 @ 000000000033e8c0] Could find no file with with path
>   'anim_render.bat4d.png' and index in the range 0-4
>   anim_render.bat4d.png: No such file or directory

does %04d resemble any variable in a batch file that does not exist outside of batch files? I could not find any similar cases so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No idea what `%04` means as far as `FFMPEG` is concerned, although `anim_*.mpg` would seem a more commonly understood method of specifying `all starting 'anim_'` Perhaps it's a special meaning `+any 4 characters` (although `????` would seem more common here.

Nevertheless, it would appear that ffmpeg is expecting that the `%` is supplied `literally` so the cure in batch would be to precede the `%` with a caret : `^%`

Erm- make that double the `%` - `^x` normally works with characters that have a special meaning in batch; seems you need `%` to escape `%`...

Comment: It specifys the pattern anim_xxxx.png like I wrote in the question. xxxx in the case of %04d is an increasing number starting from 0001.
Using ^% gives me the same error unfortunately :/
Oh and I should have mentioned, I tried * already and got the same error.

Comment: %0 in batch means 'the name of this batch file' hence since the name of your batch is "anim_render.bat" batch substitutes that for the %0 and `anim_%04d.png` becomes `anim_anim_render.bat4d.png` so theoretically, the line should become `ffmpeg -f image2 -i anim_%%04d.png -vcodec mjpeg -q:v 0 -r 25 foo.avi` - double-up the `%`

Comment: Ugh, I have no idea why but this works, even though I tried the exact same thing but getting the same error again while using the exact same script as above. Well it works now and the answer is correct, so thanks for making me try it again I guess :D

Comment: I always have trouble with it and I've done it for years on and off.  The %04d comes from the C function printf.  There it would generate 4 digit numbers with leading zeros.  It's worth looking at the longer-than-man-page documentation at http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#image2-1  Scanf is the reverse of printf and uses the same character conversions.  The numbers are expected to start at 0 unless you use -start_number.